is this a new line character input buffer?
enter image description here
when i entered number of columns, after hitting enter got the newline character within the input buffer.
enter image description here
i was expecting this kind of result.
without the char line it works.
but i want input char symbol from user, i have used scanf("%c") before char input but no changes.

Please provide a textual [mre], because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

I closed as duplicate. If you think I am wrong about what I see as duplicaste please provide the textual MRE and explain what relevant difference you see between the two.

Worth reading: https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html
